# Projecting INEGI shapefiles from Mexico

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, mexico

I have two INEGI files from Mexico (1990 and 2010) that I want to use the same projection. The 2010 file works fine (see below) and I would like the 1990 file to match the 2010 one. The shapefiles are of all of Mexico and have detailed information about various cities.  Right now, the 1990 prj file reads:

"GEOGCS["GCS_ITRF_1992",DATUM["D_GRS_1980",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]"

I'd like the file to match my 2010 file, which reads:

Projected Coordinate System:    Conica Conforme de Lambert
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  2500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -102.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    17.50000000
Standard_Parallel_2:    29.50000000
Scale_Factor:   1.00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 12.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   ITRF92
Datum:  D_GRS_1980
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

Comment: What projection are you trying to get to?

Comment: I edited my question. I just have 2 files that I want to use the same projection. They are both from different years and are all of Mexico. I just want to use the most accurate projection for all of Mexico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have constructed below a well-known text (WKT) file for the projected coordinate system that your data is using. You should copy it to a text file that has an extension ".prj". The WKT string must be a single line. Put the text file into your ArcGIS installation folder, then "Coordinate Systems, Projected Coordinate Systems". When you want to project your 1990 data, use this coordinate system as the output/target coordinate system.

Alternatively, you can import the coordinate system from your 2010 data. In some ways that's a better solution because it will ensure that the definitions match between the 1990 and 2010 data.

> PROJCS["Conic Conforme de Lambert",GEOGCS["GCS_ITRF_1992",DATUM["D_GRS_1980",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",2500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-102.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",17.5],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",29.5],PARAMETER["Latitude_of_Origin",12.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: When I tried to import the coordinate system from 2010 and apply it to my 1990 file, it ended up in a completely different area...

Comment: Apply by redefining or reprojecting? Use the project tool, not Define Project tool or the data's property page.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, I used the project tool under features. Thank you for your help!