# Projecting INEGI shapefiles from Mexico - not lining up

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, spatial-adjustment, mexico

I have two INEGI shapefiles from Mexico (2000 and 2010) that I want to line up with one another. The 2010 file projects in the right location and I would like the 2000 file to match/line up with the 2010 one. The shapefiles contain various cities in Mexico - some line up almost identically (see example of Minatitlan) while others are dramatically different (see example below of Tetepango).

I originally posted a question about getting data from 2000 to project in the correct location in Mexico, which made the cities are least be in the generally correction location! See the response here: [Projecting INEGI shapefiles from Mexico](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108015/projecting-inegi-shapefiles-from-mexico)

What can I do to make the 2000 file match/line up with the 2010 one?

2010/2000 Data Source:
Projected Coordinate System:    Conica Conforme de Lambert
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  2500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -102.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    17.50000000
Standard_Parallel_2:    29.50000000
Scale_Factor:   1.00000000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 12.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   ITRF92
Datum:  D_GRS_1980
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would not count this as duplicate post. INEGI data has changed over the years and I was hoping that some researchers who are used to using this type of data or know the format it comes in may have a suggestion as to what to do to make the various cities match better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your efforts defining projections and/or projecting your datasets have not produced a satisfactory result then I think that you should investigate [spatial adjustment rubbersheeting](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//01m80000000z000000):

> Geometric distortions commonly occur in source maps. They may be
>   introduced by imperfect registration in map compilation, lack of
>   geodetic control in source data, or a variety of other causes.
>   Rubbersheeting is used to make small geometric adjustments in your
>   data—usually to align features with more accurate information.